# How do I declare Tiff Save Options with Layer Compression value in photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to save my images in TIFF, I got the script but it doesn't work.
Please help me to fix it

```
var tiffSaveOptions = new TiffSaveOptions();
    tiffSaveOptions.imageCompression = TIFFEncoding.TIFFLZW;
    tiffSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true;
    tiffSaveOptions.saveImagePyramid = false;
    tiffSaveOptions.transparency = false;
    tiffSaveOptions.interleaveChannels = true;
    tiffSaveOptions.byteOrder = ByteOrder.IBMPC;
    tiffSaveOptions.layerCompression = TIFFEncoding.TIFFZIP; //Also RLE Option
    doc.saveAs((new File(filepath + "/" + filename + ".tiff")),tiffSaveOptions,true);
```

Comment: Have you [read this](https://asktimgrey.com/2019/02/20/byte-order-for-tiff-images/) about byte order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is an easy fix (but took a while to get there ;)

If you do want the old fashioned PC byte order it's:

```
tiffSaveOptions.byteOrder = ByteOrder.IBM;
```

although it seems to be outdated (see my [link](https://asktimgrey.com/2019/02/20/byte-order-for-tiff-images/) in the comments).

In order to save with layer compression you need to declare

```
tiffSaveOptions.layers = true;
```

and then set

```
tiffSaveOptions.layerCompression = LayerCompression.ZIP; //Also RLE Option
```

Altogether it becomes:

```
var tiffSaveOptions = new TiffSaveOptions();
tiffSaveOptions.imageCompression = TIFFEncoding.TIFFLZW;
tiffSaveOptions.alphaChannels = true;
tiffSaveOptions.saveImagePyramid = false;
tiffSaveOptions.transparency = false;
tiffSaveOptions.interleaveChannels = true;
tiffSaveOptions.byteOrder = ByteOrder.IBM;
tiffSaveOptions.layers = true;
tiffSaveOptions.layerCompression = LayerCompression.ZIP; //Also RLE Option
activeDocument.saveAs((new File(filepath + "/" + filename + ".tiff")),tiffSaveOptions,true);
```

Comment: Thank you @Ghould Fool, looks like I missed the topic, but I also need MACOS option for the other images. Anw, you are my hero :D. Thanks again.